# synclient Touchpadoff Value Changes itself

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I have ubuntu 16.04. It was working fine but suddenly now tap/scroll gets disabled in my touchpad. Then it gets enabled again and this goes on. I tried command "synclient Touchpadoff=0". But value becomes 2 itself after some time.

Also multiple press of keys in keyboard also gets disabled and enabled again.
Please help!!

Comment: Do you have key on keyboard that controls it directly, may be malfunctioning?

Comment: Its a 4 year issue, it was a issue with a faulty update. Details - https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948