# Mouse can't click on Wayland ubuntu 17.10

Tags: mouse, 17.10, wayland

I use Ubuntu 17.10 and just recently I experience mouse issue which can't click on wayland. If I switch to Xorg or unity my mouse click back to normal. The problem is I depending on wayland because my wine application works better on wayland, while on Xorg or Unity it crashes everytime I strated the program.

I already tried

> sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

but it doesn't seem bring any differences, Please help

Comment: What is the result of typing `uname -r` in the terminal?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix it's `4.13.0-25-generic`

Comment: this makes me frustated, i did a fresh install, it work for a moment but after i update and restart, the problem persist, meanwhile i'm on deadline.

perhaps the problem is on the kernel, can anyone help?

Comment: Try using `sudo rmmod psmouse` followed by `sudo modprobe psmouse` as described in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948) and let me know.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah that fix is for broken touchpad under kernel 4.13 and I was hoping it worked for mice too. Hope you find the bug soon.

Comment: I get the unresponsive mouse too after upgrading to 4.13.0-25-generic. Not sure if it's the kernel or some other update that broke it.

Comment: after fresh install for numerous of time (not to mention switching distro), mouse went back to normal, now i'm using this kernel `4.13.0-32-generic`. I'm not so sure where the problem was

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Wayland must solve this issue. Similar question was answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/975779). Worked for me.

> If you wish to do it permanently, edit
>
> /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and uncomment the line:

`#WaylandEnable=false`

> Save the file and then on reboot you will never see the cog asking for which session to use.

Comment: disabling wayland cause another problem, my wine application (skecthup) crashes everytime it started on xorg