# All input is extremley unreliable after kernel upgrade

Tags: kernel, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

So all my input is extremely unreliable (except mouse input for some reason). Holding backspace to delete letters will only delete 2 or 3 and then stop. Holding a key doesn't work anymore, it will only type one letter, and two-finger scrolling is extremely unreliable (usually does nothing but when i get it to, it stops in the middle of using it). I have no idea what to do about this. I don't want to go back to an earlier kernel, but this is making my laptop unusable.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.03 LTS

Comment: Please enter `uname -r` in a terminal and then edit the question above and add the output of that command to the quotation.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/996285/how-to-reboot-with-specific-kernel-version-if-all-else-fails

Comment: You need to write which CPU you have. And the exact version if it is from Intel.

Comment: I've written an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948).  Let me know if it helps or you have questions by adding a comment here using @WinEunuuchsToUnix in the comment.