# How to reboot with specific Kernel version if all else fails?

Tags: grub2, kernel, crash

The grub2 advanced menu crashes instantly. I can fix the problem probably, but don't have the time right now to invest hours for this problem.

**How do I reboot temporarily with specific Kernel version if all else (all the usual methods) fail?**

Intel writes about [random segfaults on current Kernels](https://www.reddit.com/r/intel/comments/7qfokt/intel_security_issue_update_meltdown_and_spectre/). Windows users also report problems.

Currently Intel acknowledged that there are random segfaults in the most resent kernel updates. This mess will prevail for the next weeks to months, especially for people with newer CPUs. It is advised on reddit.com to use a rolling release like Arch, since Ubuntu doesn't work in a setting were up-to-date software is needed; such as for current Intel CPUs.

Comment: PS: I have a degree in CS and have been using Linux since 2000. The last time I had such a mess was with the 'FUCK YOU NVIDIA' situation.

Comment: nVidia is always driving me nuts. Nouveau too for that matter. What is your main Ubuntu menu kernel version (use `e` key to see it if you don't know) What kernel versions are on your Advance Menu? Hopefully one of them works, else we'll have to boot with Live USB and install a kernel that works.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I can boot my current Kernel, version "4.14.13-041413-generic". Do you know how I can use `e` key to boot another kernel from the 'advanced menu'? I mean I can copy the entry from the grub menu and write it after pressing 'e'? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I've been using 4.14.13 for a few days now and it works perfect for me. Do you have problems? Just highlight a menu option on **Advanced Options** sub-menu and press `e` to edit it. Should work I think. There is no clipboard where you can copy and paste in Grub that I know of. In the old days we had things called paper and pen :D