# Can't install 4.13.0-26-generic headers

Tags: linux-headers

I'm trying to install kernel headers for 4.13.0-26, but they don't seem to be available (need them to install VMware worksation 14).

```
$ uname -r

4.13.0-26-generic

$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic' has no installation candidate

$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (4.13.0.25.26).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Comment: It appears that the kernel headers for this version of the kernel have been deleted?
  https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/xenial/main/base/linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic

Comment: Here's a similar link where the change log has **not** been deleted like it was in your link: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/updates/linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic

Answer (score 0):

## Too long for a comment

My tests are too long to fit in a comment so pardon my break from tradition in posting the results in an answer. Remind me later and I'll delete this answer.

#### Current kernel version

```
$ uname -r
4.14.13-041413-generic
```

#### Look for Kernel header 4.13.0-26

```
$ apt list linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic
Listing... Done
linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security 4.13.0-26.29~16.04.2 amd64
```

#### Install Kernel header 4.13.0-26

```
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-gcp-tools-4.10.0-1008 linux-gcp-tools-4.10.0-1009 linux-headers-4.10.0-38
  linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic linux-headers-4.10.0-40
  linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-101
  linux-headers-4.4.0-101-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-103
  linux-headers-4.4.0-103-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-98 linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic linux-image-4.10.0-40-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-40-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-38-generic linux-signed-image-4.10.0-40-generic
  linux-tools-4.10.0-1008-gcp linux-tools-4.10.0-1009-gcp
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-26
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-26 linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
Need to get 11.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 83.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

## Summary

On my system at least there doesn't seem to be a problem with installing 4.13.0-26 Linux headers. However there have been many problems reported with [Ubuntu LTS kernel version 4.13.0-26](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948).