# How to get the disk space used by Ubuntu back after failed installs?

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 2 times, but I failed. The first time, I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows, but it never booted! Still, it occupied about 44 gigabytes of disk space. The second time I gave my laptop to my friend and she installed it again (alongside Windows 10) but she failed to boot it after the install too. Now, for the third time, I want to install it but not alongside Windows.

If I select **Erase the disk and install Ubuntu**, would it then delete the previous failed Ubuntu install files or not? And if it doesn't, then how can I delete them and free up the disk space they occupy?

Comment: Yes, "erase the disk" should delete all partitions on the whole hard disk and create new ones for Ubuntu using all available space.

Comment: I think you mean disk space not memory, but I understand your question. If you select erase the disk, it will erase everything, including windows and anything else. Personally, I always choose 'something else' and configure my partitions manually. If you absolutely want to wipe everything on your disk then by all means select erase everything. To 'get the space back' you just need to delete the partition and expand an adjacent partition.

Comment: **DO NOT ERASE WINDOWS** You have tried twice to install Ubuntu alongside Windows and both times Ubuntu failed to boot. Now you are proposing to erase Windows and installing Ubuntu a third time and it may fail to boot. This will transform your working laptop into an interesting looking brick on your coffee table. First question. Is your Live USB downloaded between Jan 8 2018 and Jan 21 2018? If so read this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/998471/razer-blade-stealth-disk-corruption-fsck-needed-probably-samsung-ssd-bug-afte/1000454#1000454

Comment: It is important to have a working copy of windows to download BIOS and Firmware updates from Manufacturers' websites. It is important to have working copy of windows to create new Live USBs. Also there may still be data files on Windows you forgot to backup. You can always shrink the size of the Windows Partition and still keep Windows installed.

Comment: @M.Becerra Please see my answer below and kindly consider retracting your close vote.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I considered it and declined because your answer is a duplicate of Journeyman Geek's answer to the linked duplicate question. Duplicate answers don't bother me much if they're good enough and your answer is good enough, however I'm also not at all enamored of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`erase the disk and install Ubuntu` option will erase the everything on hard drive, re-partition it and install ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to delete the Ubuntu Partition already created from the first two failed attempts. On your third installation attempt (hopefully this time with a new Live USB) simply choose to install it over the old (failed) Ubuntu Installations.

As I stressed in comments **DO NOT ERASE WINDOWS** thinking it will make a third attempt at installing Ubuntu magically successful.

It is important to have a working copy of windows to download BIOS and Firmware updates from Manufacturers' websites. It is important to have working copy of windows to create new Live USBs. Also there may still be data files on Windows you forgot to backup. You can always shrink the size of the Windows Partition and still keep Windows installed.

There are known problems from January 4, 2018 with Ubuntu Kernels: [Touchpad gestures and holding keys does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948). As your question was posted on January 16, 2018 your Live USB could have kernel bugs that have been subsequently fixed.

There could be other reasons why the first two installations failed. The important thing is to find out why the first two installations failed. A knee-jerk reaction of deleting Windows is not the solution.