# Why does my 16.04 install keep randomly freezing?

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox, freeze, iwlwifi

My installation has been fine up until a few days ago when an update caused things to act up. I thought it was the new kernel it installed but switching back to 4.10.0-28-generic resulted in the same thing. 
I am running 16.04 LTS on a Dell Latitude E6410 with 8gb ram and nvidia 3100m under the open source drivers. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ufwvUGUAo-rDE9CK04aFlbl0-2c4ttoZ/view?usp=sharing 
that is my syslog file. At around 23:11 and 23:24 is where I see some odd things. The system hangs at 23:27 as per my notes. When it hangs it is totally unresponsive. Keyboard and mouse fail to work and no HDD activity on the light. I have 2 other log files 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11I2va9bygapm9N34G6W2QEi1HBzKXSk5?usp=sharing Scrolling from the bottom you can tell what is from the reboot and what is right before the freeze.
Things went sour after 4.13.0-26-generic was installed. At the time I was using NVIDIA drivers. But I had to strip them and go to the default.
`Jan 19 23:26:40 hal9000 NetworkManager[989]: <info>  [1516422400.7814] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Jan 19 23:26:40 hal9000 kernel: [ 3710.891778] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 38:0e:4d:cd:c7:0d
Jan 19 23:27:35 hal9000 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 19 23:27:35 hal9000 systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Jan 19 23:27:35 hal9000 systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Jan 19 23:27:35 hal9000 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 19 23:27:35 hal9000 systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Jan 19 23:27:35 hal9000 systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Jan 19 23:27:35 hal9000 systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for wavebox...
Jan 19 23:27:35 hal9000 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for wavebox.
Jan 19 23:27:36 hal9000 kernel: [ 3766.731880] audit: type=1400 audit(1516422456.665:40): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.wavebox.wavebox" pid=13583 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3/event3
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0/event0
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2/event2
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6/event5
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 systemd-udevd[13602]: Process '/lib/udev/snappy-app-dev change snap_wavebox_wavebox /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0 226:0' failed with exit code 2.
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 systemd-udevd[13602]: Process '/lib/udev/snappy-app-dev change snap_wavebox_wavebox /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1 0:0' failed with exit code 2.
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 systemd-udevd[13599]: Process '/lib/udev/snappy-app-dev change snap_wavebox_wavebox /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-2 0:0' failed with exit code 2.
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 systemd-udevd[13606]: Process '/lib/udev/snappy-app-dev change snap_wavebox_wavebox /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1 0:0' failed with exit code 2.
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 systemd-udevd[13605]: Process '/lib/udev/snappy-app-dev change snap_wavebox_wavebox /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-VGA-1 0:0' failed with exit code 2.
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input14
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input16
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input17
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input15
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 NetworkManager[989]: <info>  [1516422457.2743] device changed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/eno1, iface: eno1)
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input14/event13
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input17/event16
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input16/event15
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input15/event14
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 NetworkManager[989]: <info>  [1516422457.3860] device changed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0, iface: wlp3s0)
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12/event11
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-0:1.0
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13/event12
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10/event9
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11/event10
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.8
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.8/2-1.8:0.0
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.8/2-1.8:0.1
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 kernel: [ 3767.580648] audit: type=1400 audit(1516422457.514:41): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/3748/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=13620 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 kernel: [ 3767.581116] audit: type=1400 audit(1516422457.514:42): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/3748/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=13620 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 kernel: [ 3767.581405] audit: type=1400 audit(1516422457.515:43): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/3748/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//snap_update_ns" pid=13620 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 kernel: [ 3767.595722] audit: type=1400 audit(1516422457.529:44): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=13733 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/platform/PNP0C14:00/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00/9DBB5994-A997-11DA-B012-B622A1EF5492/input/input9
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input8
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7/mouse1
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input8/mouse0
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 systemd-udevd[13602]: Process '/sbin/crda' failed with exit code 234.
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 systemd-udevd[13600]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event8' (scan code 0x150, key code 190): Invalid argument
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/platform/PNP0C14:00/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00/9DBB5994-A997-11DA-B012-B622A1EF5492/input/input9/event8
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/event4
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7/event7
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input8/event6
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 upowerd[1401]: (upowerd:1401): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/virtual/input/mice
Jan 19 23:27:37 hal9000 NetworkManager[989]: <info>  [1516422457.7099] device changed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
Jan 19 23:28:58 hal9000 gnome-session[1991]: cp: cannot create directory '/home/user/snap/wavebox/75/.local/share/mime': File exists
Jan 19 23:28:59 hal9000 gnome-session[1991]: Failed to rename /home/user/snap/wavebox/75/.local/share/mime/application/vnd.sun.xml.calc.xml.new as /home/user/snap/wavebox/75/.local/share/mime/application/vnd.sun.xml.calc.xml: No such file or directory
Jan 19 23:29:03 hal9000 Wavebox[13825]: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Jan 19 23:29:03 hal9000 Wavebox[13825]: Failed to load module "gail"
Jan 19 23:29:03 hal9000 Wavebox[13825]: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Jan 19 23:29:03 hal9000 Wavebox[13825]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Jan 19 23:29:06 hal9000 dbus[953]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Jan 19 23:29:23 hal9000 io.snapcraft.Launcher[1761]: 2018/01/19 23:29:23.022072 userd.go:89: Starting snap userd
Jan 19 23:29:23 hal9000 gnome-session[1991]: method return time=1516422563.106782 sender=:1.151 -> destination=:1.150 serial=3 reply_serial=2
Jan 19 23:29:23 hal9000 gnome-session[1991]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:2384): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:212: Error during inserting events: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.zeitgeist.EngineError.InvalidArgument: Incomplete event: interpretation, manifestation and actor are required
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.923878] wrong command queue 19 (should be 4), sequence 0x5359 readp=65 writep=65
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.923919] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.923940] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 414 at /build/linux-hwe-UY0ygs/linux-hwe-4.13.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/tx.c:1748 iwl_pcie_hcmd_complete+0x3fa/0x480 [iwlwifi]
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.923941] Modules linked in: nvram msr pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) dell_rbtn dell_laptop dell_smm_hwmon snd_hda_codec_hdmi arc4 iwldvm mac80211 intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel binfmt_misc kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd intel_cstate snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm dell_wmi input_leds joydev dell_smbios snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event dcdbas sparse_keymap wmi_bmof serio_raw snd_rawmidi intel_ips lpc_ich snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer iwlwifi cfg80211 snd mei_me mei soundcore shpchp acpi_als kfifo_buf dell_smo8800 industrialio mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 nouveau mxm_wmi i2c_algo_bit ttm
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.923984]  psmouse drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect ahci sysimgblt fb_sys_fops firewire_ohci libahci e1000e sdhci_pci drm firewire_core sdhci crc_itu_t ptp pps_core wmi video
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924000] CPU: 3 PID: 414 Comm: irq/28-iwlwifi Tainted: G        W  OE   4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924001] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude E6410/ , BIOS A17 05/12/2017
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924002] task: ffff9c319a420000 task.stack: ffffbaf4c176c000
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924011] RIP: 0010:iwl_pcie_hcmd_complete+0x3fa/0x480 [iwlwifi]
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924012] RSP: 0000:ffffbaf4c176fd10 EFLAGS: 00010282
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924014] RAX: 0000000000000048 RBX: 00000000000003e8 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924015] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff9c31abcd3578 RDI: ffff9c31abcd3578
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924016] RBP: ffffbaf4c176fd60 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 0000000000000a67
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924017] R10: ffff9c3112177000 R11: 0000000000000a67 R12: 0000000000000019
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924018] R13: 0000000000005359 R14: 0000000000000013 R15: ffff9c319f234320
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924019] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9c31abcc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924020] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924021] CR2: 00007f8ceceff000 CR3: 00000001d0c0a006 CR4: 00000000000206e0
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924022] Call Trace:
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924039]  ? iwl_rx_dispatch+0xd3/0xf0 [iwldvm]
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924046]  iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x5fd/0x980 [iwlwifi]
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924054]  iwl_pcie_irq_handler+0x46d/0x9d0 [iwlwifi]
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924062]  ? irq_finalize_oneshot.part.38+0xf0/0xf0
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924064]  irq_thread_fn+0x20/0x50
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924066]  irq_thread+0x13c/0x1a0
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924068]  ? irq_forced_thread_fn+0x70/0x70
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924071]  kthread+0x109/0x140
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924073]  ? free_irq+0x70/0x70
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924074]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924079]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924081] Code: ff e9 74 fe ff ff 45 8b 8f a8 00 00 00 45 8b 87 ac 00 00 00 41 0f b7 cd 44 89 f6 48 c7 c7 00 8a 5e c0 4c 89 55 d0 e8 47 ac 91 c5 <0f> ff 4c 8b 55 d0 6a 01 b9 10 00 00 00 6a 20 ba 02 00 00 00 41 
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924107] ---[ end trace 38f23d46201ab004 ]---
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924110] iwl data: 00000000: ec 01 80 0a 24 a4 59 53 7a 17 6c a5 0e e2 d6 80  ....$.YSz.l.....
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924114] iwl data: 00000010: 97 f8 ab 98 3c b1 c6 ca 53 51 41 7d 7a 4b ed a4  ....<...SQA}zK..
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938679] wrong command queue 24 (should be 4), sequence 0x5892 readp=65 writep=65
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938724] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938748] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 414 at /build/linux-hwe-UY0ygs/linux-hwe-4.13.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/tx.c:1748 iwl_pcie_hcmd_complete+0x3fa/0x480 [iwlwifi]
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938749] Modules linked in: nvram msr pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) dell_rbtn dell_laptop dell_smm_hwmon snd_hda_codec_hdmi arc4 iwldvm mac80211 intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel binfmt_misc kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd intel_cstate snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm dell_wmi input_leds joydev dell_smbios snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event dcdbas sparse_keymap wmi_bmof serio_raw snd_rawmidi intel_ips lpc_ich snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer iwlwifi cfg80211 snd mei_me mei soundcore shpchp acpi_als kfifo_buf dell_smo8800 industrialio mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 nouveau mxm_wmi i2c_algo_bit ttm
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938792]  psmouse drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect ahci sysimgblt fb_sys_fops firewire_ohci libahci e1000e sdhci_pci drm firewire_core sdhci crc_itu_t ptp pps_core wmi video
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938810] CPU: 3 PID: 414 Comm: irq/28-iwlwifi Tainted: G        W  OE   4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938811] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude E6410/ , BIOS A17 05/12/2017
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938812] task: ffff9c319a420000 task.stack: ffffbaf4c176c000
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938821] RIP: 0010:iwl_pcie_hcmd_complete+0x3fa/0x480 [iwlwifi]
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938822] RSP: 0000:ffffbaf4c176fd10 EFLAGS: 00010282
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938824] RAX: 0000000000000048 RBX: 00000000000002d0 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938825] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff9c31abcd3578 RDI: ffff9c31abcd3578
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938827] RBP: ffffbaf4c176fd60 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 0000000000000a89
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938828] R10: ffff9c319ff97000 R11: 0000000000000a89 R12: 0000000000000012
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938829] R13: 0000000000005892 R14: 0000000000000018 R15: ffff9c319f234320
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938830] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9c31abcc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938832] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938833] CR2: 00007f8f8412a000 CR3: 00000001d0c0a004 CR4: 00000000000206e0
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938834] Call Trace:
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938851]  ? iwl_rx_dispatch+0xd3/0xf0 [iwldvm]
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938860]  iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x5fd/0x980 [iwlwifi]
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938870]  iwl_pcie_irq_handler+0x46d/0x9d0 [iwlwifi]
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938878]  ? irq_finalize_oneshot.part.38+0xf0/0xf0
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938880]  irq_thread_fn+0x20/0x50
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938883]  irq_thread+0x13c/0x1a0
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938885]  ? irq_forced_thread_fn+0x70/0x70
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938888]  kthread+0x109/0x140
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938890]  ? free_irq+0x70/0x70
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938892]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938897]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938899] Code: ff e9 74 fe ff ff 45 8b 8f a8 00 00 00 45 8b 87 ac 00 00 00 41 0f b7 cd 44 89 f6 48 c7 c7 00 8a 5e c0 4c 89 55 d0 e8 47 ac 91 c5 <0f> ff 4c 8b 55 d0 6a 01 b9 10 00 00 00 6a 20 ba 02 00 00 00 41 
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938932] ---[ end trace 38f23d46201ab005 ]---
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938953] iwl data: 00000000: ec 01 80 0a b1 14 92 58 3c 05 f9 bd 77 a7 42 21  .......X<...w.B!
Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938958] iwl data: 00000010: 3e 68 30 2f be 1a 31 19 3e 5f 0e 0b d0 17 79 43  >h0/..1.>_....yC`

Comment: Please copy/paste log files to http://pastebin.com, and post links here.

Comment: The 512 byte limit would require me to know exactly where in the log the information needed is.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jessepage1989/1278deaeded621440bca9712cc7205b2

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with the iwlwifi driver. There is some odd logs pertaining to that driver

Comment: Some have had success moving from kernel `4.13.0-26` to `4.14.13`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948

Comment: @mikewhatever I added a gist github link of the log file. I have removed my pcie wireless card from the laptop and I have been using a usb alfa card now for the past 3 hours. So far so good. Going to continue through the weekend and see what happens. I think there is an issue with the iwlwifi driver

Answer (score 0):

`Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.924000] CPU: 3 PID: 414 Comm: irq/28-iwlwifi Tainted: G        W  OE   4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu`

Found a thread with a similar issue. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=224938 .
It was suggested that the issue may be with virtual box modules.

`Jan 19 23:29:26 hal9000 kernel: [ 3876.938749] Modules linked in: nvram msr pci_stub ***vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE)*** dell_rbtn dell_laptop dell_smm_hwmon snd_hda_codec_hdmi arc4 iwldvm mac80211 intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel binfmt_misc kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd intel_cstate snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm dell_wmi input_leds joydev dell_smbios snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event dcdbas sparse_keymap wmi_bmof serio_raw snd_rawmidi intel_ips lpc_ich snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer iwlwifi cfg80211 snd mei_me mei soundcore shpchp acpi_als kfifo_buf dell_smo8800 industrialio mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 nouveau mxm_wmi i2c_algo_bit ttm`

So I decided to blacklist the modules listed when executing `lsmod | grep vbox`

by entering them into **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire.conf** as per https://linux-audit.com/kernel-hardening-disable-and-blacklist-linux-modules/

Needless to say I haven't had any more freeze ups. Been running for a couple hours with `tail -f /var/log/syslog` running without any of the previous errors showing up.

There seems to be an issue with Virtual Box 5.2.6 and the iwlwifi driver. I don't think It has a lot to do with kernel 4.13.0-26-generic as I had the same issue when I booted into previous kernel version. 4.4 and 4.10

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/linux-what-is-a-tainted-kernel is an interesting writeup that help me understand what the "Tainted" meant.