# Ubuntu 16.04 Freeze Randomly - Not solved

Tags: kernel

My problem is simple but I am almost one year with it, without a final solution. I have an Asus Laptop with Ubuntu 16.04, one year ago I made a reinstall of Ubuntu 16.04 (before that, my Ubuntu 16.04 works fine) and started the problems. My laptop freeze randomly, i can't use the mouse or keyboard, the screen is on but it's freeze, I can't shutdown my laptop. It can be two hours after turn it on, it can be six, it can be twelve; it happend making anything, when I update softwares, when I browse on internet, etc.

One month ago, I changed my Laptop's Cooler and then I formated the laptop and install a basic copy of Windows 10 for testing. I used it for a week and the problem didn't happend, so I formated again and install Ubuntu 16.04 (because I need it for work). Well, the problem is back. So I read all question here with this problem, but the anwsers doesn't work with me.

- I tried to update kernel, from 4.13 to 4.15. The random freezes still. So I came back to 4.13.0-32-generic (my actual version).
- I tried [this solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1511019/comments/8) with the grub and c-state. The random freezes still.
- I tried to switch the drivers [like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/955523/791094). The random freezes still.
- I tried some patches of [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051) (its hard understand what patch is useful, and follow the conversation). The random freezes still.
- I made a Disk comprobation with GSmartControl, and my disk health is good.
- I installed and run tlp. The random freezes still.
- I updated intel microcode. The random freezes still.
- I changed to kernel 4.4.0-112-generic (my actual kernel). The random still (random happend with 4.4.0-112-generic, 4.13.0-32-generic and 4.15).
- I checked the hardware with a technician. The cooler is new (less than one month of use), and we didn't find problems on hardware. Freeze still.
- T switch from Unity to Gnome. Random freeze still.

I really don't know, everything fails. This is my Laptop specifications like say "inxi -ACDMNSG":

```
System:    Host: xxxxx-U36SG Kernel: 4.4.0-112-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Unity 7.4.0  Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   Mobo: ASUSTeK model: U36SG v: 1.0
           Bios: American Megatrends v: U36SG.202 date: 10/19/2011
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-2450M (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 2494 MHz 2: 2494 MHz 3: 2494 MHz
           4: 2494 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF119M [GeForce 610M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.5 driver: nvidia
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.02hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce 610M/PCIe/SSE2
           GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.111
Audio:     Card Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.13.0-32-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
           driver: iwlwifi
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet driver: atl1c
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 750.2GB (4.6% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST9750423AS size: 750.2GB
```

Im going to appreciate any help with this.

**EDIT:** I tried tlp, update intel microcode and switch to kernel 4.4.0-112-generic. Random freezes still. Please, I need help with this.

**EDIT2:** I have one syslog more: https://gist.github.com/ibuioli/cb509b1417f28b4dbb90e2ae804cb08f Look at Feb 10 18:21 (last log before freeze, 18:28 was the reset). It say this:

```
Feb 10 18:21:15 ignacio-U36SG gnome-session[2524]: [10052:10091:0210/182115.522763:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(381)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
```

**EDIT3:** When I did `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -B9 Tainted` I got this one time: https://gist.github.com/ibuioli/dc48e04816627c6a9768af62622324a2

**EDIT4:** The freezes still even with the recent updates, the freezes happens when I am using the laptop or event when is suspended. When the freeze happens, the Power Light still ON, the CPU Light is always OFF (not blink) and, sometimes, the Bloq-Mayus Light blinks steadily.

Comment: There are many people running kernel patches with a great deal of success: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051 (Hit the End key and then scroll up for recent messages).

Comment: Sorry, I ran some patches past week and the freezes problem still. I will test another, but my CPU is not on the Baytrail list.

Comment: I had problems of my own with `4.15` kernel so I would try `4.15.1` which came out yesterday. You can also try `4.14.17` because `4.14.xx` is a five year Long Term Support (LTS) kernel. Many won't support you here unless you are on kernel `4.13.0-32` though as `4.14.xx` and `4.15.xx`are Linux kernels and not Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: Ok I will back to 4.13.0-32, but they recommend the update to 4.15 in first place.

Comment: I'm just saying on this website most people will not offer help if you are running kernel `4.15`. On the launchpad.net website developers often recommend trying `4.15` to see if the problem goes away. To file your bug report you should be running `4.13.0-32` (or the most current **supported** kernel) in the first place. Also make sure you are running `thermald` and `tlp` for general intel cpu smooth processing. Make sure your intel microcode is up-to-date.

Comment: That's a good data! I will check. Yes, I come back to 4.13.0-32. I will test.

Comment: When you do reboot with `4.13.0-32` remember to update your question with new stats because currently they say: `Host: xxxx-U36SG Kernel: 4.15.0-041500-generic x86_64 (64 bit)` which will lead some people here to say **"that's not supported!"**

Comment: You're welcome. I should have said in the first place you should try running Kernel `4.10-0-42` which was working over the last year. Lot's of people had problems starting with kernel version `4.13.0-26`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948

Comment: Thanks, I will try again but I am updating Kernel since 4.4 (since agost 2017). I will give a try to kernel 4.10.

Comment: 4.4.0-112 is also a great idea!

Comment: I updated my question. I switch to kernel 4.4.0-112, install tlp, update intel microcode and the random freezes still happend. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try kernel `4.14.18` but I don't know if that will change things.

Comment: Sorry, I tried three difference Kernels. I think that's not the problem. I will test if this happend just with Firefox. The Ubuntu System freeze complety, no keyboard, no mouse, even sound stop; just the screen is ON (but without process data, I know because this happend playing videos and the videos stop). The USB still giving power (the mouse have LED ON when the freeze happen). And this happend since a half-year ago, with dual-boot and without dual-boot.

Comment: I agree it doesn't sound kernel related. The only advise I could give is to file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

So I also had a problem similar to this. [Why does my 16.04 install keep randomly freezing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998165/why-does-my-16-04-install-keep-randomly-freezing/998826#998826)

It had something to do with my wifi driver. I never go it worked out. I ended up just paying $10 for a new wifi card. (AR9280 AR5BHB92). I had a Intel 633ANHMW card running the same iwlwifi driver. Haven't had a problem since the change over.Run a `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -A9 Tainted` and see if you get any hits.

When you log in run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a separate terminal and see if anything suspicious populates while you are logged on.

EDIT: Correction try `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -B9 Tainted` .  See if you have any warnings.  It should tell you modules involved with the warning.

*sorry for the answer but I cannot post comments yet*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73011/discussion-on-answer-by-jessemp-ubuntu-16-04-freeze-randomly-not-solved).

Answer (score 0):

Consider this can be a hardware problem, even if you hadn't the same issue on Windows for a week. To me, it looks like a memory problem (RAM), in a way that your computer cannot even dump what is happening.

Try to run a full memory test - usually hardware vendors ship this in the computer, otherwise you can use the memtest from Grub boot screen as well.

Comment: I will check that, yesterday I could get this log with `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -B9 Tainted`: https://gist.github.com/ibuioli/dc48e04816627c6a9768af62622324a2

Comment: Well, even to me look like a memory problem but the memtest go well. I test 8 loops, every fine, it give me "Ok".