# Inconsistent Trackpad Movement

Tags: gnome, mouse, touchpad, 18.04

After a recent update to Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS my trackpad's movements have been inconsistent. I turned the acceleration to zero through the xset command, but the problem still occurs.

I duel booted windows and tested the trackpad on their with no issue, so I assume this isn't hardware related.

---

System:

- Synaptics Touchpad
- Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What does `uname -r` display when you type it in the terminal?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix 4.13.0-30-generic

Comment: Sounds related to this [4.13.0-26-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948) update problem. Last user with touchpad problem reported success upgrading kernel to `4.14.14-041414-generic` just yesterday.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm now running 4.14.14-041414-generic but the issue still persists. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Check the second answer on the link above. It deals with Ubuntu 17.10 update. Also remove the kernel 4.14.14 so you get back onto regular kernel updates on the 4.13 kernel chain which is supported. Removing kernels is described in the link above..

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that worked, thank you!

Comment: 18.04 is not yet released.  Please confirm the version of Ubuntu you are on.

Comment: @ThomasWard sorry should I have clarified. I asked this question when using 17.10 but the answer still works for me even though I upgraded to 18.04 (I'm currently on 18.04 on my Razer Blade). I'm new to this, should I have left it a 17.10? I thought it would have been better if I updated the question as this solution works on 18.04.

Comment: @ceiphr we just don't support 18.04 here because it's not yet released and still technically in development.  The Help Center even says this.  But the point is that 18.04 is still under development so things might change/explode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd the same problem, it could be a driver touchpad issue.

[--> Check also Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/996369/292634)

In my case, I had a conflict between the old synaptic driver and the new libinput package. This topic helps me : [Debian GNOME: touchpad settings missing. Use libinput instead of synaptics](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292350/debian-gnome-touchpad-settings-missing-use-libinput-instead-of-synaptics)

After fresh install of libinput, I ran :

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

And my touchpad works again