# Repeating characters printed in terminal (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: gnome-terminal

Whenever I start my terminal I get a glitch. It automatically starts writing `^[[2~` repeatedly and doesn't allow me to type `exit`. I already tried installing Ubuntu again. I have a Dell Inspiron 3542.

What should I do?

[image: Terminal Image]

Comment: You might have a keyboard key stuck down

Comment: I also tried disconnecting keyboard.

Comment: How do you start it? Did you Try Alt+F2 to launch by command? Did you try Ctrl-Alt-F1 to change to a full screen console? There you have to login, and get a system shell too. Same problem? Alt-F7 brings you back into the windowworld. You could install a different shell from synaptics to inspect the problem further.

Comment: This ***might*** be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948