# Ubuntu 16.04 not booting 4.13.0-x-generic

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, updates

I was using version 4.10.0-42-generic before and it worked fine. I can still choose it in GRUB but the new versions I got from updates do not work.

The new versions that do not work are 4.13.0-26-generic, 4.13.0-32-generic, neither upstart or recovery mode.

There is no error message or anything when I choose those, it just restarts my computer and I am back in GRUB. I am worried that I will run into problems if I keep use the old version later on. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Kind regards

Comment: 4.13.x under 16.04 seems to be [unstable](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1742603) and there are some [reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/+bug/1742626) about it. currently it is advised to either upgrade to 4.14.x or user an older kernel until the issues are resolved

Comment: Additional info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948