# Wifi is down again

Tags: networking

I installed ubuntu 16 for like a few months, everything worked fine until last week. The wifi just went down suddenly, and I've tryied pretty much every methods on the internet and no use. (driver is installed)

And when I do ‍‍‍‍‍`ifconfig`, the `wlp4s0` is not showing up, `iwconfig` says no wireless extension. 
    I check couple networkconfig files, all wireless settings were enabled.

Another thing that I noticed is that, whenever I turned off the bluetooth, the network is swtiching to airplane mode.

Comment: If it is a laptop, is there a physical switch for the wireless that is turned off? What is the output of **sudo rfkill list**

Comment: Not really, I haven't disabled anything. And I've already tried to reinstall 16.04(worst senario), and wifi still doesn't show up. So I go back to 14.04 and it worked this time..... Looks like something went wrong with the updates

Comment: I've had wifi problems ever since, but usually I just reinstall the b43 driver. But this time everything won't get it work

Comment: An update likely broke your Wifi. This happened to many users in different areas. Boot with an older kernel version or install a newer version as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948