# Ubuntu 17.10, kernel 4.13.0-32 won't boot

Tags: boot, kernel, 17.10

I rebooted my system this morning after it installed the new kernel, and was startled to find it not booting (hanging at the splash screen with no disk activity).  After turning off the splash screen and quiet, I see a bunch of messages something like "Failed to connect to lvmetad.  Falling back to internal scanning".

I can boot the 4.13.0-31 kernel just fine.  How can I go about debugging this?  I've found lots of references to issues with the -31 kernel, but none about the -32 kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the Kernel to 4.15 fixed this for me.
I used ukuu which makes it nice and easy.
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu

Although now I'm running into issues with there being no extras packages and not being able to run docker :(

Comment: A new user like Jim Carey can benefit from a link on how to upgrade to Kernel 4.15. Your answer could for example include a link like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165

Comment: I actually ended up downgrading to 4.13.0-16

Comment: Make sure you pin 4.13.0-16 so it doesn't get removed until you're ready. There were lots of problems after 4.13.0-26: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work