# alt+ctrl+f1 screen is showing ^@^@^@

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, bug-reporting

When I tried

```
sudo showkey -k
```

the result is

```
keycode 213 press  
keycode 213 release
..
```

in a continuous loop.

Please help me.

Comment: It might be related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work