# Keys get "stuck" randomly and type endless line of a particular letter/command

Tags: keyboard, 18.04

I have a strange problem in Ubuntu 18.04 (I use a DELL Latitude E5550): sometimes when I type, some keys get "stuck", meaning that when I type "i", the result is an endless line of i-s ("iiiiiiiiiiiiii"). If backspace gets stuck, entire texts I wrote are deleted. I can stop this by pressing some other button.

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 16.04 while using the same laptop. I "solved" this issue by setting the keyboard to write only one character when I press down a button. However, this possibility seems to be missing from Ubuntu 18.04.

A few days ago I ran a hardware diagnostic, which found no problems on the hardware side.

Comment: Looks like you need to replace the keyboard.

Comment: If keyboard doesn't exhibit same behavior in Windows then bug may be related to this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work

Comment: Hi Sipos, can you add the output of `uname -a` to your question?

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand what 'add the output of uname -a' means,  sorry :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04 issue this command:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat
true
```

If the result is `true` then turn off keyboard repeat using this command:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat false
```

The other related commands you can use are:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay
uint32 500
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat-interval
uint32 30
```

Comment: This really made my day! It worked on ubuntu 18.04 I run the first 2 commands and boom it worked

Comment: This just blocks repetition of characters. It doesnt allow me to reenter same character even if I purposely want to do it without repressing the key.

Comment: @OmkarKulkarni The design of this answer is to turn off keyboard repeat. You will need to search deeper for the solution to your problem or, post a new question with your particulars.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the same with GUI (works on Ubuntu 22.04):

`open settings` -> `accessibility` -> `typing` -> `repeat keys` (turn off repeat keys)

The CLI approach mentioned before did not disable `repeat keys` settings in practice, at least for my ubuntu version.