# I need a proper fix for keyboard keys stuck randomly

Tags: keyboard

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I've got this [keys getting stuck randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029776/keys-get-stuck-randomly-and-type-endless-line-of-a-particular-letter-command) issue.

All the answers I've found recommend to turn off "Repeat keys" completely, which means I cannot hold a key for a sequence of letters, neither hold the arrow keys to navigate through texts and web pages. For a software developer this results in a terrible user experience.

Is there a way to fix this issue properly?

Comment: Have you tried anther keyboard?

Comment: The fix indeed will be to invest in a keyboard that functions correctly.

Comment: I have tried plugging other keyboards to my laptop and the issue stays the same.