# Two finger scrolling stopped working suddenly

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, mouse-scroll

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Thinkpad T480, and two finger scrolling wasn't working at seemingly random times, and now it doesn't work at all.

Could use some help troubleshooting.

Comment: Not sure but you might find some clues here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this same problem
You can restart the touchpad by:
`sudo modprobe -r psmouse`
Then,
`sudo modprobe psmouse`
If you have this problem whenever you wake from suspend, then copy this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    # Place your pre suspend commands here, or `exit 0` if no pre suspend action required
    modprobe -r psmouse
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    # Place your post suspend (resume) commands here, or `exit 0` if no post suspend action required
    sleep 2
    modprobe psmouse
    ;;
esac
```

Now, place it in the /usr/systemd/system-sleep folder, and name it whatever you want.
Now, type `sudo chmod +x "whatever you named your script"`

Comment: Will check if this works the next time it happens. I'll try suspending now. Not sure if that's the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Closing the lid to suspend and waking the laptop back up fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an option in the settings. Check under the touch pad settings, or try reinstalling touchpad drivers.